# When is an SSL certificate 'valid' - altnames

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've been using an online SSL checker to check certificate validity for several sites.

One thing I noticed is that many websites have wildcard certificates - especially those hosted on common web hosting sites, such as goDaddy: `*.onlinestore.godaddy.com`

But those sites have custom domains and so when validating the SSL cert I can see an error where the hostname does not match the altnames listed in the certificate.

But all major browsers (tested chrome, FF, IE and Safari) still show the site as secure. Do the browsers not care that the domain names are not listed in the cert, and isn't that a security vulnerability?

**Example**: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.cinnamonmotif.com

Comment: It sounds like your online checker is wrong, and since you haven't named it, nor provided a concrete example, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: As long as the wildcard rule is matched, the certificate is indeed valid. For example for the given certificate, `foo.onlinestore.godaddy.com` or `test.onlinestore.godaddy.com` are valid names, but `bar.godaddy.com` is not.

Comment: Example added - and in this case it does not match the wildcard rule listed in the cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case a wildcard certificate is installed on a domain, the browser only check the certificate validity and wildcard rule. As long as this rule is true the certificate id trusted and no warning appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the certificate that the browser resolved you'll see that it's different than sslshopper.com resolved.

When you go in a modern browser the client sends the TLS Server Name Indication  extension, and the site notices that it's supposed to serve up the cinnamonmotif.com certificate.

SslShopper saw `*.onlinestore.godaddy.com`, which is certificate `0x6068c7475ab4ee2a` from `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2`.

With SNI the served up certificate is `cinnamonmotif.com`, certificate `0x3e0240d9425e8120` from `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2`.

The fact that the browser saw a different certificate, which *is* a hostname match, is why the browser says it's a legitimate connection.